# Creating a form in the partials of a rendered collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rendering a collection of `Posts`:

In posts_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @posts = Post.where("user_id = ?", id)
end
```

In show.html.erb:

```
<ol>
  <%= render @posts %>
</ol>
```

In _post.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [post, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

The `form_for` in `_post.html.erb` is so someone can add a comment to any of the rendered posts. Comments are also of class Post. This means in the `posts_controller` I need something like `@comment = Post.new(post_params)` for the form in the partial. If I were only rendering a single Post this wouldn't be a problem. However, I am rendering a collection of Posts, each of which needs a `@comment` instance variable passed to it. How do I create a `@comment` instance variable in the `posts_controller` for each post? And how do I pass these `@comments` to the partials? And what's the correct code in `form_for` in the partial?

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly build the comment for each post like below,

```
 def show
   @posts = Post.where("user_id = ?", id)
   @posts.each{|post| post.comments.build}
 end
```

and use the same in form,

```
<%= form_for [post, post.comments.last] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

This will build the comment for every post while rendering the page, which can be accessed  by `post.comments.last`. Comment won't exist in database until the comment form associated with post is submitted.

**Note:** Need to modify `post.comments.last` if default scope is changed http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: Question: Why are you using post.comments.last?. My guess is that everytime you create a comment it's removed from the array, but still can't get your logic.

Comment: Because we are building one (with `post.comments.build`)  which can be  accessed using `post.comments.last` unless modified default `scope.` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class. As using the `build` will not create any actual `comment` unless the comment form associated with post is submitted.

Comment: @RailsOuter updated answer to address your concern. Thanks for  raising it.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that each post contains a/many comment and build those

```
class Post   
   attribute :comments, type:Comment, typecaster: Comment, default: []
end


Class Comment
end
```

Now in the form you can simply render using

```
<%=@post.comments%>
```

`PS : Do not keep comment as a post type if you want to avoid rendering comments for comments and so on.(You can use the same type as well)`